# Looking for the name of a Sci Fi book about a dystopian future earth with no medical services

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi, dystopia

So this is killing me...

I read the book some years ago.

My premise was that I do not read enough different authors, so I started picking books at random going down the alphabet.

This book was pretty far down the shelf of my library at the time, close to "Zhan".

The premise of the book was that medicine is bad, in prolonging life unnecessarily.
So all medicine was banned.

Our young protagonist finds a medic bag in an old ambulance, and starts saving people.
Leading to some unfortunate consequences.

It was called Dark Wing, or Night Wing, or some such.

Please help.

Comment: Please note that we don't close questions as duplicates [without there being an accepted answer on both](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774)

Comment: Sorry, I will study the rules a bit more closely.

Comment: Pannies, apparently you were right about the title, it is [*Dark Wing*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?530733). For future reference, if you have the title of a written work of science fiction or fantasy, you can probably find it in the ISFDB.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Rules? They just make them up as they go along. This one about not closing story-id dupes has only been a rule for a few days.

Comment: Pannies, if you accept this identification, please signify by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @user14111, but if one didn't expend a lot of energy on discussion trivia then what would be the point of a site like this :-)

Answer (score 2):

As [identified here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84168/dystopian-story-where-medicine-is-illegal) this is [Dark Wing](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?530733) by  Katherine MacLean and Carl West,.